# iPhone text messages never get delivered

Tags: iphone, messages, sms

Text messages are disappearing when sent *between two iPhones*.

The issue of iMessage losing messages sent to users who have switched to non-apple devices is [well documented](http://www.theverge.com/2014/11/9/7183507/apple-tool-deregister-imessage-phone-numbers-released), but in this case we're seeing one iPhone user message another, and the message never gets through. There's no indication on the sender's side that the message failed- we just happened to notice it on our own. It's happened at least twice within the past few months (though probably a lot more)

Here's the latest example. My friend asks a question, and I respond a couple of minutes later, but she never gets it on her end- though everything looks fine on my side:

[image]

[image]

One possible clue: Her question was sent as an SMS, not an iMessage (which apparently [happens](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/imessages-being-sent-as-text-messages) when a phone can't access normal data coverage - hence the green bubble.) Did that somehow cause my subsequent reply to get lost?

Whatever the case, there's no technical excuse for a queued messaging system to be silently vanishing messages- Apple's got some explaining to do.

**UPDATE:**

My friend just received the missing message on Feb 7, eleven days after it was sent...

Comment: +1 for the screenshots and details. Just curious, do you remember if it said "Delivered" after you sent the lost message?

Comment: @bassplayer7 - Can't remember if it said "Delivered"- Wish I had noticed, but by the time we realized the message had failed it was several hours later.